# NServiceBus Timeout Polling

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using the SQL persistence for timeouts and I was wondering what the polling strategy is for it. We'd like to run some end to end testing so we're setting the timeout to occur in the past by just updating the `time` in the database. In some cases the polling seems to happen in about 60 seconds and the timeout fires but as the service stays up for longer the polling interval seems to get longer. Is there an back-off in the timing and if so is there any way to short circuit the polling so it happens more frequently in our testing environment?

This is NSB 5.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This line in NServiceBus](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.Core/DelayedDelivery/TimeoutManager/ExpiredTimeoutsPoller.cs#L124) GitHib repo says it all.

It polls every single minute, or less, depending on what it finds on timeouts in the datastore. Comment above it explains the why.